# NewView in CustomCursorAdapter is not getting called

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-cursoradapter

I have this CustomCursorAdapter taking a cursor from another Activity.

```
public class PastJourneyListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "<PastJourneyListAdapter>";
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Cursor cursor;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public PastJourneyListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        cursor = c;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        Log.d(TAG, "6" + c.getColumnCount() + c.getCount() );
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        Log.d(TAG, "1");
        TextView journeyTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.past_journey_title);
        journeyTitle.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));

        TextView journeyPlace = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.past_journey_place);
        journeyPlace.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("place")));

        TextView journeyDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.past_journey_date);
        journeyDate.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "4");
        final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.past_journey_list_item, parent, false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

**PastJourneyList.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.past_journey_list);

    JourneyDataSource jds = new JourneyDataSource(this);
    jds.open();
    Cursor c = jds.getAllJourneys();

    ListView pastJourneyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.addFriendsList);
    pastJourneyListViewAdapter = new PastJourneyListAdapter(getBaseContext(), c);
    pastJourneyListView.setAdapter(pastJourneyListViewAdapter);
}
```

Somehow I am getting a **NullPointerException**. 
**Also the log shows that neither newView() nor bindView is getting called!** However, the constructor is getting called and printing perfect results of cursor.

TIA

**Error Log **

```
12-06 06:51:47.445: D/<PastJourneyListAdapter>(2429): 671
12-06 06:51:47.455: D/AndroidRuntime(2429): Shutting down VM
12-06 06:51:47.455: W/dalvikvm(2429): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415d78b0)

12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.memories/com.example.memories.pastjourney.PastJourneyList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at com.example.memories.pastjourney.PastJourneyList.onCreate(PastJourneyList.java:35)
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-06 06:37:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Sir, post the error please..NPE..

Comment: can you post reasonable-(relating) codes from this class PastJourneyList or probably post this line  com.example.memories.pastjourney.PastJourneyList.onCreate(PastJourneyList.java:35)

Comment: @Elltz Added that method. Sorry I didn't think anything would be wrong there. As I can print the cursor count in the adapter also.

Comment: @Elltz Problem solved. Thanks a lot! Just bcoz of you. But can you tell me if my adapter is efficient performance-wise. I read many articles but not able to decide whether to use viewholder here.